# Spring Boot 3.1 + Bouncy Castle has very slow startup time

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, bouncycastle, web-push

I have Spring Boot project with Gradle and Java 17.

I add dependency

```
     implementation("nl.martijndwars:web-push:5.1.1")
     implementation("org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk18on:1.70")
```

And after adding `implementation("org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk18on:1.70")` spring boots startup time increase from 15 seconds to **4 minutes!** with 100% load of CPU

I think this is because of BouncyCastle library, but I do not know how to run it faster.

P.S. No code changes! I just add dependency and run app.

Do you have some ideas for fixing it?

I tried other versions of library with the same result.

Comment: If this is inside a virtual machine or container, one possibility is lack of entropy. Another common cause of startup issues in the past has been implicit first-time generation of DH parameters (instead of configuring a standard group for example); some sample stack traces would be helpful to diagnose that or to point to the culprit in any case.